# How can I Reference Functions Above when they are defined?

Tags: python, function, reference

For example I have a goodbye ascii art message that I want to display when i type "exit". But if I refernce it ABOVE it's place where i define it, then it'll give me an error. If I put it above the reference point, then it works, but it doesn't look the best. Is there a way to be able to summon a function before it's seen by the program? Thank you:)

Comment: I recommend simply getting used to the look of function calls being below their definitions.

Comment: Not even in Javascript (pretty much the world's most modern commonly used scripting language) has this feature. In DOM JS, you have document.onready, but that's pretty much the extent.

Comment: This is, because programming languages have always been written this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you can get close:

```
def main ():
    # ... Do things
    f ()
    # ... Do other things

def f ():
    print ('hello')

main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you want you can put that function in another file and import it so that the main file looks pretty

main.py

```
from other import exit

# do something

exit()
```

other.py

```
def exit():
    print("ASCII goodbye")
```